# Python searching for particular child of child

Tags: python, xml, parsing, search

I am trying to download xml data (which I have done) parse it (which I have done) and search through xml data to return a result.

```
<Substances>
<Name>Substance 1</Name>
<Product>
<Product_name>Product ABC</Product_name>
<MRL>0.0123*</MRL>
</Product>
<Product>
<Product_name>Product XYZ</Product_name>
<MRL>0.0234*</MRL>
</Product>
</Substances>
<Substances>
<Name>Substance 2</Name>
<Product>
<Product_name>Product ABC</Product_name>
<MRL>0.789*</MRL>
</Product>
<Product>
<Product_name>Product XYZ</Product_name>
<MRL>0.567</MRL>
</Product>
</Substances>
```

After saving the xml file locally (because it's pretty large), I want to search for a substance, say, "Substance 2", and then search for a product name, "Product XYZ", then search for a MRL data under that product particular to that substance.

(Note, substances are all unique, but products are not, because products are repeated under every different substance)

To be more clear I will give an example: if the substance search term was "Substance 2", and the product search term was "Product XYZ", the the program would return "0.567".

[edit]
The part of my code relating to this question so far is:

```
substance='Substance 2'
product_name='Product XYZ'

for mrl in root.findall(substance):
    for prod in find(product):
        print(mrl.text)
```

This doesn't throw an error, but it doesn't print any output either.

[\edit]

Please let me know if more details are needed. Help appreciated.

Comment: Where is your code ? What have you tried that didn't work ? We're all glad to help, but you have to show some real effort at solving the problem first...

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers I will edit the question to add my code (which wasn't working)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this tutorial https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html

```
for substance in root.find('Substances')
  if substance.find("Name").text = "Substance 2":
    for product in substance.findall('Product'):
        if  product.find('Product_name').text == 'Product XYZ':
            return product.find('MRL').text
```

Comment: My code is now:
`code`
for s in root.findall('Substances'):
    if s.find("Name").text==substance:
        for p in s.findall('Product'):
            if p.find('Product_name').text ==product:
                mrl=p.find('MRL').text
                print ('MRL of ',substance,' for ',product,' is',mrl)
`code`

Which works well. Thanks!